# How to prevent system call in awk to return exit code, or how to format it?

Tags: linux, awk

Using awk, the `system` command returns the command output AND the exit code.

However, there is a new line between the output and the exit code, which I really don't want.

Example:

```
BEGIN {
    FS = ","
}
{
    print system("echo toto")
}
```

Outputs on a file of a few lines:

```
toto
0
toto
0
toto
0
toto
0
toto
0
toto
0
toto
0
toto
0
toto
0
toto
0
toto
0
```

From another post I tried the following to remove the new line:

```
printf "%s,", system("echo toto")
```

But it has the following result:

```
toto
0,toto
0,toto
0,toto
0,toto
0,toto
0,toto
0,toto
0,toto
0,toto
0,toto
0,
```

How can I either:

- prevent the system call to return the exit code ?
- format correctly the output and exit code so that each exit code is after (or before) the command output ?

Comment: `system` command is a way to call shell commands in `awk`, when you print its status(status of bash command from `awk` side and toto is being printed by shell command), for your shown examples you can simply usr `print` statement of `awk` itself to avoid this writing of status code from shell commands IMHO.

Comment: @RavinderSingh13 print system("echo toto") also prints the exit code after a new line

Answer (score 6, accepted):

awk's `system()` never 'returns' any output. If the command it runs writes output, the output goes directly without any modification to stdout -- in your case, since you didn't redirect it, to your terminal. `system()` returns *only* the exit status, and `print system()` prints that status plus a newline, again to stdout because you didn't redirect it.

To capture the output from a command and manipulate it in awk, use `stringcommand | getline [var]` repeated if necessary to get multiple lines and followed if necessary by `close(stringcommand)` to get the status.

```
$ seq 5 | awk '{"echo toto"|getline x; print NR ":x=" x ",status=" close("echo toto") " and Robert is the brother of your parent"}'
1:x=toto,status=0 and Robert is the brother of your parent
2:x=toto,status=0 and Robert is the brother of your parent
3:x=toto,status=0 and Robert is the brother of your parent
4:x=toto,status=0 and Robert is the brother of your parent
5:x=toto,status=0 and Robert is the brother of your parent
```

Comment: Is it possible to include a variable in the string ? Because the following throws an error:  "echo "$1" toto "| getline toto   >>> /bin/sh: 1: toto: not found

Comment: ("echo "$1" toto ") | getline toto
Got it.

Comment: @FlorianCastelain - no, `"echo "$1" toto "` would leave the string that `$1` contains unquoted in the shell and so open to all sorts of undesirable effects. Use `echo \047" $1 " toto\047"` or similar instead. It's also not safe to use `getline` unprotected like that and blindly use the value you **hope** it populated without checking if it succeeded or not, and you should store the command you'll execute in a variable so you can use it in the pipe to `getline` and then exactly again in the `close()`, see http://awk.freeshell.org/AllAboutGetline

Answer (score 0):

In fact, under **certain** circumstances, you *indeed* can leverage `system()` to directly get the output you desire, without having to deal with formatting a command, running it through getline, storing it temporarily, resetting RS (if you've set it to "^$" before), and to also close that command before returning the output, as such :

```
-rw-r--r--  1 501  20  77079 Jul 26 13:07 ./selectWoo.full.min.js.txt

valid file :: exist_and_non_empty

non-existent file :: cannot locate

32297  gprintf '\033c\033[3J'; echo; ls -lFGnd "./selectWoo.full.min.js"*; 
       mawk2 'function filetest(fn) { 
          gsub(/\047/,"&\134\047&",fn); # in case single-qt in filename
          return 
              system(" exit \140 [ -s \047"(fn)"\047 ] \140 ") 
              ? "cannot locate" 
              : "exist_and_non_empty" 
       } BEGIN { 
           ORS = "\n\n"; 
           fn_pfx="./selectWoo.full.min.js";
           print "\nvalid file :: "      filetest(fn_pfx ".txt"); 
           print "non-existent file :: " filetest(fn_pfx ".txt_fake") 
      }' ; 
      history 1 ; echo
```

I'm only making it more verbose here for illustrative purposes. Instead of returning whether the `system()` call was successful or not, we directly set the exit code to be that of the file test.

If you want to simplify the return to be boolean, then make it

> `return ! system(…)`

- I haven't tested every POSIX file/directory info check flag out there, but I can't imagine there are more than a handful that might fail this code.

You can also perform other tasks, too, as long as the outputs are non-negative integers (assume they will `exit_code % 256` before returning, as long as you're comfortable interpreting that output. quick example (`\047` is single quote `'` , `\045` is percent `%`, 140 is grave-accent **[ ` ]** )

```
mawk2 'BEGIN { a = "0123456789ABCDEF"; print 
    system(" exit \140 printf \047\045s\047 \047"(a)"\047
             | wc -c \140 "); }'
```

which properly prints out "16" for measuring length of string.

**I'm fully aware this is a horrible way of using system( ) and POSIX exit codes.**